# How to get the length of a repeated nested field in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery where I have a repeated nested field called `author_names`. [image]

How can I get the length of the repeated nested field `author_names`? 
e.g. for `article_id = 2049807276`, the length of the author names would be 2.

I prefer the standard-sql syntax in bigquery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [`ARRAY_LENGTH()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_length) function

as in

```
#standard SQL
SELECT article_id, ARRAY_LENGTH(author_names) len
FROM `table`
```